# Android -hardware acceleration set in manifest but still showing unset in View subclass

Tags: android, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I am showing an animation and want to allow the GPU to keep using the same hardware layer, so in the android manifest I set the android:hardwareAccelerated attribute to true as the following activity definition demonstrates:

```
<activity
       android:name=".mysplashScreenActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Then, in the activity, I check if hardware acceleration is turned on. However, it keeps returning false. Here is how I am evaluating if it is turned on:

```
boolean isAcelerated = someView.isHardwareAccelerated();
```

Why am I not able to turn it on when I am using a high end LG G2 phone for testing? I also confirmed my phones GPU type, its Adreno (single core GPU by Qualcomm). I'm targeting API 16+.